# WebStorm files with some extensions are changed to ? and cant open it

Tags: webstorm

I'm using WebStorm for developing my project. Yesterday while adding a file with name **'core.module.ts'** , suddenly all the file with the extension **'.module.ts'** are suffixed with symbol **'?'** and am not able to open it. If I double click the file, it opening in **'Firefox browser'**.

I don't know what I exactly did while adding **'core.module.ts'**, it asks some popup, I just given **OK** for all.

**PS :**  If I opens any project in my WebStorm it behaves like the same.
**PFA : Attached the image below**

[image]

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types` -- go through each file type and look for a `*.module.ts` or similar pattern. Quite possibly you will need to remove it (but make a screenshot before doing it, just in case).

Comment: @LazyOne i can't find one file **.module.ts**, in all the file types

Comment: Right now I do not have any better ideas than suggesting to double check it (especially "Files Opened in Associated Applications" type -- based on the "opens in browser" behaviour you have described). Also check `options/filetypes.xml` file (show it here or share) -- should be in `~/Library/Preferences/WebStorm2017.1` folder as per https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: If nothing -- provide your `idea.log` (Help | Show Log in...) -- maybe it will have some hints.